# Remove package from winget package list without uninstalling

Tags: windows, uninstall, package-management, winget

> Synopsis: I used Winget to install an application that had an auto
> updater, such as Discord. The issue here is that if the Discord app
> upgrades itself,the Winget will be unable to detect the change in
> version.

I'd like to remove the application from the Winget package list without uninstalling it.